# os module, trying to recognize the path of a file

Tags: python

I built this little program called `Assembler.py`:

```
 def main(argv):
     temp = os.path.realpath(argv[1])
     if temp.endswith(".asm"):
         print(temp)
     else:
         print("submit a valid file")

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     main(sys.argv)
```

I'm running this with some script I built:

```
python Assembler.py $1
```

example for running:

```
Assembler pong.asm
```

I don't know why `if` is wrong. Why my address is not ending with `.asm` ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the `if`. Didn't you forgot to add `import os` and `import sys`? If not - what is the behaviour of the script and the expected one?

Comment: what actually happens when you try to run the code.

Comment: Have you considered using os.path.splitext?

Answer (score 0):

Your all code like this:

```
#coding=utf-8

import os
import sys

def main(argv):
     temp = os.path.realpath(argv[1])
     if temp.endswith(".asm"):
         print(temp)
     else:
         print("submit a valid file")

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main(sys.argv)
```

Then, you should use `python Assembler pong.asm` directly.
Example:

```
C:\Users\ou\Desktop\test>python test.py xyz.asm
C:\Users\ou\Desktop\test\xyz.asm
```

Comment: i'm trying, and this happens:

 File "Assembler", line 1
    python3 Assembler.py $1
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: If you use python3, please delete `#coding=utf-8`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the `if`. The problem is with the shell script and the way you are trying to run it.

If you want to run your python code directly you should run

```
python Assembler.py pong.asm
```

The `.py` extension is important!

If you want to write simple shell script to wrap that. You can create file named `Assembler` with following content:

```
python Assembler.py $1
```

To run that simple shell script you should run:

```
./Assembler pong.asm
```

or

```
sh Assembler pong.asm
```

Where `./` or `sh` is required.